# ¿Cómo separar los campos concatenados en MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Una consulta por favor. Requiero poder separar los campos concatenados (comenzando por Ms, Mr. Dr. Mrs luego el nombre, apellido título del cargo, desde y finalizar con fecha y hora) debo agregar dentro de la concatenación la palabra **Trabaja como** después del apellido para identificar el cargo de cada persona, así como también después del cargo agregar la palabra **desde** para cerrar con fecha y hora.

Estoy trabajando con la tabla empleados (employees) de la base de datos **Northwind** **de MySql**

La sintaxis que estoy trabajando en la siguiente:

```
select concat(TitleOfCourtesy, FirstName, LastName, Title, BirthDate) Nombrecompleto
from employees
```

**Debería listarse de esta forma:**

```
Ms. Nancy Davolio trabaja como Sales Representative desde 1948-12-08 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Imagino que puede hacerse con `substring_index()` para la separación, y empalar variables para la concatenación, veamos que ideas proponen otros usuarios.

Comment: porfavor indicame que retorna exactamente esa sintaxis, si no me equivoco seria: Ms. Nancy Davolio Sales Representative 1948-12-08 00:00:00

Comment: Gracias por la atencion, deberia retornar la informacion de la siguiente forma: Ms. Nancy Davolio trabaja como Sales Representative desde 1948-12-08 00:00:00'

Comment: Es impresionante que trabajen desde su fecha de nacimiento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disculpa si no es la respuesta pero así te entendí.

- Deseas concatenar valores en formato de string al resultado de una consulta que obtienes de tu base de datos
- Entonces solo debería bastar con pasarle todos los argumentos necesarios separados por comas en el lugar donde esperas que aparezcan de este modo:

Aquí declaro una variable:

```
SET @ValorNuevo = 23;
```

Aquí la sentencia SQL en la cual concatenaré múltiples parámetros

```
SELECT CONCAT("Hola hoy es: ", NOW(), " No lo puedo creer ", "además tengo: ", @ValorNuevo)
```

Dando como resultado:

```
Hola hoy es: 2019-10-04 17:07:06 No lo puedo creer además tengo: 23
```

Dentro de tu `CONCAT` y:

- Los valores que vienen de la base de datos, tendrán el nombre de la columna a recuperar
- Aquellos valores que son *strings* deberán ir entre comillas
- Aquellos valores que sean variables entonces deben estar precediddas por el símbolode `@`
- Las funciones propias del gestor de bases de datos deben ir sin comillas y con la sintaxis que este mismo exige para que funcionen por ejemplo el caso de `NOW()`

Quedando tu consulta así:

```
select concat(TitleOfCourtesy, FirstName, LastName, 
              "trabaja como ", Title, " desde ",BirthDate) Nombrecompleto 
from employees
```

Comment: Me parece muy acertada tu respuesta, ya que la idea de lo que quiere hacer en la concatenación se resuelve ampliamente, dejando que con lo aprendido pueda desarrollar la consulta de acuerdo a su necesidad.